# Unable to Install Client Side QC 10.0

Tags: quality-center, mstest

Unable to Install Quality Center Client Side on the client's machine.

Operating System: Windows Vista *****
IE Version:****9*******

We tried all the basic trouble shooting steps like deleting TD_80 folder from %temp% and performing a fresh installation.

Deleting Mercury Intercative folder from
C:\program files\common files

Running the internet explorer as Administrator.

None of the above solved the problem

we are recieving the below error message:::::

HP Quality Center: Unrecoverable Error Occured.

Reason: Could not load file or assembly 'interop.OTAClient, Version=10.0.02469,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=792843134cf0407a' or Contact your site administrator.

Details::::

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'interop.OTAClient, Version=10.0.0.2469, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=792843134cf0407a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'interop.OTAClient, Version=10.0.0.2469, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=792843134cf0407a'
at Mercury.TD.Client.Ota.Core.Application.SSPREnabled(String serverUrl)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.ConnectionManagementService.Initialize()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.BaseService.Initialize(IServiceManager serviceManager)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceFactory`1.CreateService()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.b__0()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.CreateService(ServiceConstructorDelegate`1 serviceConstructor, T& service)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.GetServiceEx(ServiceConstructorDelegate`1 serviceConstructor)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.GetService()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.ServiceCache`1.GetBaseService()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.DoPublish[T](IServiceFactory`1 factory, Boolean activate)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ServiceManager.PublishAndActivate[T,C]()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.ApplicationServicesPlugin.PublishServices(IServiceManager serviceManager)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.ApplicationService.InitializePlugins()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Services.ApplicationService.Start(Application application)
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Application.Start()
at Mercury.TD.Client.UI.Core.Application.Initialize(String url, String configFilePath, IDictionary`2 properties)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Please help resolving this issue.

Also instead of running as Admin, why cant we run IE as normal user ?

Regards,
Srihari
404-579-5368

Answer (score 2):

The following steps may help to get QC working in IE9 with Windows 7. Not quite the same environment, but its worth a shot.

1. Adjust your user account control settings to 'Never notify'. This requires a reboot.
2. Disable any proxy account settings that you may have configured in Internet Options.
3. Try installing the QC explorer app. It is a tool that HP provides that allows access to QC without using a regular internet browser. Make sure to install the tool 'as administrator'. You then point the app to the QC server and the files should be installed. Once the files are installed it should work when using IE.
4. Ensure that you are using the 32bit IE.